# async / await continuation

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

In the code below I need to execute the three Get... methods in parallel.  When a Get... method completes I need to immediately call the Save... method.  Note Save... takes thing as a parameter.
All Get and Save methods must complete before DoStuffAsync returns.

My guess is that I need a continuation on the Get... methods but I dont know how to construct it.

```
protected async void DoStuffAsync()
{
    SomeThing thing = new SomeThing { ID = 5 };
    SomeRepository rep = new SomeRepository();

    // We need to run all three Get... methods in parallel
    // As soon as a Get... method completes we need to save the result to the correct property on thing and call the Save... method .

    var getRed = rep.GetRedAsync().ContinueWith<Task<string>>(async x => { thing.Color1 = x.Result; await rep.SaveRedAsync(thing); return x; }); // does not compile
    var getBlue = rep.GetBlueAsync();
    var getGreen = rep.GetGreenAsync();

    string red = await getRed.Result; // this is not good because getBlue may finish before getRed.  We want dont want to wait on getRed before calling SaveBlue
    await rep.SaveRedAsync(thing);
    var b = await getBlue;  
    var c = await getGreen;

    // thing must be fully initialized before DoStuffAsync returns

    }


public class SomeThing
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Color1 { get; set; }
    public string Color2 { get; set; }
    public string Color3 { get; set; }
}

public class SomeRepository
{
    public async Task<string> GetRedAsync()
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => "red");
    }

    public async Task<string> GetBlueAsync()
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => "blue");
    }

    public async Task<string> GetGreenAsync()
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => "green");
    }

    public async Task SaveRedAsync(SomeThing thing)
    {
        // We need thing.ID here as well as other properties
        await Task.Delay(1);
    }

    public async Task SaveBlueAsync(SomeThing thing)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1);
    }

    public async Task SaveGreenAsync(SomeThing thing)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: When you have code that you think would work but doesn't compile, please include the compilation error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would not mix `ContinueWith` and `await` and rather use an `async` lambda directly:

```
protected async Task  DoStuffAsync()
{
    SomeThing thing = new SomeThing { ID = 5 };
    SomeRepository rep = new SomeRepository();

    // We need to run all three Get... methods in parallel
    // As soon as a Get... method completes we need to save the result to the correct property on thing and call the Save... method .

    Func<Task<X>> getRedFunc = async() =>
    {
        var result = await rep.GetRedAsync();
        thing.Color1 = result;
        await rep.SaveRedAsync(thing);
        return result;
    };

    var getRed = getRedFunc();

    var getBlue = rep.GetBlueAsync();
    var getGreen = rep.GetGreenAsync();

    await Task.WhenAll(getRed, getBlue, getGreen);
}
```

Also, don't use `async void` methods for anything but event handlers. You won't be able to observe the completion of a method like this or handle exceptions possibly thrown inside it.

Comment: Do you have a justification behind "I would not mix ContinueWith and await?"

Comment: @NStuke, not necessarily in this order, but: 1) Code structuring and readability; 2) differences in how current `SynchronizationContext` and `TaskScheduler` are being taken into account, 3) differences in how exceptions are handled and propagated; 4) differences in how continuations lambdas are run (people tend to forget about `ExecuteSynchronously`); 5) I'm sure I've missed something else but that should be enough :)

Answer (score 8):

Well, you *could* explicitly use `ContinueWith` - or you could break off each "get and save" into a separate async method or async lambda. For example:

```
async Task GetAndSaveRedAsync(SomeThing thing, SomeRepository rep)
{
    var red = await rep.GetRedAsync();
    thing.Red = red;
    await SaveRedAsync(red);
    // Return red if you want (change the return type to Task<string>)
}

// Ditto for the others
```

Then:

```
protected async void DoStuffAsync()
{
    SomeThing thing = new SomeThing { ID = 5 };
    SomeRepository rep = new SomeRepository();

    var handleRed = GetAndSaveRedAsync(thing, rep);
    var handleBlue = GetAndSaveBlueAsync(thing, rep);
    var handleYellow = GetAndSaveYellowAsync(thing, rep);

    // Or use Task.WhenAll
    await handleRed;
    await handleBlue;
    await handleYellow;
}
```

Comment: Why would someone write a async task with an await for another task. Why not just write a task and in this call the "normal" not async method. Since your task already runs on a different thread the synchc method won't block UI. But calling a task within a task and await that one isn't this unnecessary overhead?

Comment: @RandRandom: What makes you think that anything is running on a different thread? Yes, you *can* use `Task.Run` and dedicate a thread to this, but why would you want to create more threads than you need?

Comment: So I guess you are saying that a task doesn't run on a different thread? I thought that's the only reason you ever write a task so it can run async in a different thread.

Comment: @RandRandom: Not necessarily, no. It *might* do, but it certainly doesn't have to. Consider a WinForms app which contains `async void HandleButtonClick(...) { button.Text = "Waiting"; await Task.Delay(1000); button.Text = "Waited"; }` - there are no extra threads involved there. It's probably worth you reading up on async again :)

Comment: That's for sure. :) seems like the async keyword automatically let me believe that it will always run on a different thread.

Comment: @RandRandom common mistake. The async keyword does nothing regarding threads. In fact for client apps, you will often want to stay on the same thread for all your work. What you WANT however is all your I/O to be async and threadless. You should read Steven Cleary's post on the subject.

Comment: Thanks Jon this is the way to do it I believe.  With regard to @RandRandom's observation: You pretty much dodged his question. Yes this will run a thread inside a thread and its not as simple as plain ol TPL. Indeed, the more I use TAP the more I am convinced it is not worth it's weight.  It works its way into the 95% of my code that cant be paralellized and the for the 5% that can, it's not as elegant as TPL.

Comment: It is very interesting to note that there is little if any debate on the web (that I can find) that focuses on PRACTICAL implementations of TAP versus just using TPL where necessary.  This is a bit a rant, sorry, but I think its relevant here.

Comment: @user579342: There's no such thing as a "thread inside a thread", and the code I've given *won't* start any new threads at all. I didn't dodge RandRandom's question so much as question its fundamental assumptions. You seem to be assuming that TAP is about parallelism - it's not, it's about asynchrony, which is different.

Answer (score -1):

You can try parallel framework:

```
using System.Threading;

using System.Threading.Tasks;

Func<Task<string>>[] functions = { rep.GetRedAsync, rep.GetBlueAsync, rep.GetGreenAsync }; 
Var[] GetArray = new Var[functions.Length]
int i=0;
Parallel.ForEach (var function in functions)  
{  
             GetArray[i++]=function();

}
```

**Note**: Require `.Net 4`